# how to create costume marker icon rails google maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am developing google maps project so i want create costume marker icon here my code in javascript
    `window.onload = function initmap() {
      var markers = <%=raw @json.to_json %>;
      var icon = {
        url: '/home/amarnath/Project/myCarparking/app/assets/images/001-map.svg',
        size: new google.maps.Size(15, 20),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(15/2, 20/2)
      };

```
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_places"));

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      var geolocpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
      var mapOptions = { 
        center: geolocpoint,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_places"), mapOptions);

      var geomark = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: geolocpoint,
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: 'Your geolocation',
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
      });

      for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i];
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: data.marker_title,
          icon: '/home/amarnath/Project/myCarparking/app/assets/images/parking_full.png'
        });

        (function (marker, data) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
            infoWindow.setContent(data.infowindow);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });

        })(marker, data); 
      }
    });
  }
}`
```

and i getting error like this

```
parking_full.png:1 GET http://localhost:3000/home/amarnath/Project/myCarparking/app/assets/images/parking_full.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your icon to /assets/images folder and add following code:

```
icon: "/assets/parking_full.png"
```